# Unknown Device in power notifications

Tags: security, power-management, notification, unknown-device

I'm new to Ubuntu. I kept seeing power notifications and assumed they were for the battery. But then I found that they actually were for another device: `ELAN2514:00 04F3:262C`.
That device is unknown to me.

I don't have anything connected to my laptop and have no idea what it is. The unknown device seems to be out of battery now for the last few days, and doesn't charge when the laptop is charged.

I'm not computer savvy but I did [probe URL](http://linux-hardware.org/?probe=1111ffc9e6) to find the unknown device, but it's not listed.

However, under the probe status info circles, it indicates an Acer/Aspire notebook & desktop. Those are also unknown to me. Are they related to the unknown `ELAN2514:00 04F3:262C` device?

What is that device(s) and does it indicate my computer might be hacked?

Please also see the following screenshots:

[image: unknown device that has no power keeps showing up in security logs]

[image: unknown device showing in power setting]

[image: unknown device in security log]

Comment: Do you have a touchscreen?

Comment: I do have a touchscreen and it is working